# mysql query to search a table name from multiple databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am facing a problem in searching a particular table_name.
I have around 50 databases on the server and i wish to search a table_name say X is created in which all databases.
Is there any straight-forward to find the exact databases in which X table is found in MYSQL through phpMyAdmin.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Well there is the `SHOW TABLES` sql extension offered by mysql. But you would have to make a script iterating through all databases on all servers. No difficult, just two loops inside each other, but I see no way around that...

Comment: `information_schema` database is there to store the meta data about all the databases, tables, columns of your mysql instance. Look at my answer below and check whether it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `information_schema` database for this. The below query will return the names of all the databases, which contains the table `your_table_name`.

```
SELECT `TABLE_SCHEMA` 
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` = 'your_table_name'
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

According to the `MySQL` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) about `information_schema` database,

> INFORMATION_SCHEMA provides access to database metadata.
>
> Metadata is data about the data, such as the name of a database or
>   table, the data type of a column, or access privileges. Other terms
>   that sometimes are used for this information are data dictionary and
>   system catalog.

Answer (score 0):

Please query the `information_schema`.`TABLES` with `table_type='BASE TABLE'` and providing the name of the table(`table_name`).

This query will give us all the tables with `'<your_table_name>'` in all the databases that are currently in our server.

Please change `'<your_table_name>'` as per your requirement.

```
 SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
    where table_type='BASE TABLE'
    and table_name =  '<your_table_name>'
    limit 100;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.